# Website not working if www is in URL

Tags: web-server, .htaccess, dns-zone, magento

I am forcing my webserver to rewrite a none www URL to www, e.g. `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`, via `.htaccess`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But my site does not load with **www** and prints **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**.

If I enter a URL like `https://www.example.com/some-uri` then I get redirected to `https://example.com`

DNS Zone Records
[image: DNS Zone Record]

What might be the cause?

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. It was a magento setting. [More infos](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/1338/66769)

Comment: _Aside:_ Any reason why you are not redirecting to HTTPS with your `.htaccess` redirect?

Comment: @MrWhite, no, It is just dev .htaccess. I think I could just use `RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]` instead of `RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

Comment: Write a proper answer.

Comment: Yes, if your site is HTTPS then you should simply redirect to `https://...`. The directive as it stands would keep the user on HTTP - if that was requested. Unless you have something before that redirects to HTTPS? (And/or possibly result in a 2nd redirect to HTTPS later?)

Comment: @Sven, I wrote a proper answer, but it was moved to the comment section.

Comment: I don't see an answer converted to a comment. Also: An answer should never consist of a link only to prevent link rot (even within the SE network).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. It was a magento setting.

There is a setting in `system->configuration->Web->Url Options->Auto-redirect to Base URL`. Set that to '**No**'.

Comment: I can accept this answer in 2 days.

Comment: If that solved the problem, then the base URL is almost certainly wrong. Check it and fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @MichaelHampton. You are right, I also had to change the Base URL in the backend (for secure and unsecure) from `https://mycompany.de/` to `https://www.mycompany.de/`